# the link is not available about how to install groovy on Windows, what should I do?

Tags: windows, groovy

I am learning Groovy, and I want to install Groovy on Windows, but the relevant link is broken on the Groovy website:

1. Open this link：http://groovy-lang.org/install.html#_installation_on_windows
2. Click on the "NSIS Windows installer"
3. Then I get a error(404)

Is there any other way to install Groovy on Windows?

Comment: I think link doesn't "work" because it contains `TODO` tag: `http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/TODO-Windows+NSIS-Installer`.

Comment: yeah, I think you are right, and I'm looking for other ways(thank you for your editing)